# Astronomical Plotting Techniques in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, astronomy

I am new to python and am currently in the process of attempting to plot the retrograde motion of mars. I have a txt file that has R.A. and Declination in addition 12 other rows of data (like apparent magnitude etc). However, from that file I am trying to convert only the R.A and Dec. to decimal degrees in order to create a scatter plot with dec on the x axis and R.A. on the y axis. After researching I discovered that atrophy/skycoord may be the best tool to use. The problem I am having is how to code the conversion for the two specific rows of data I'm needing. Any help is greatly appreciated![][1]

I am currently in the process of attempting to plot the retrograde motion of mars. I have a txt file that has R.A. and Declination in addition 12 other rows of data (like apparent magnitude etc). However, from that file I am trying to convert only the R.A and Dec. to decimal degrees in order to create a scatter plot with dec on the x axis and R.A. on the y axis. After researching I discovered that atrophy/skycoord may be the best tool to use. The problem I am having is how to code the conversion for the two specific rows of data I'm needing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
f = open("Mars2.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
df = pd.read_csv('Mars2.txt', sep=";", names=['Date(0 UT)','Apparent R.A.','Apparent Declination','Distance to Earth','Distance to Sun','App. Mag.','Ang. Diam.','Phase Illum','Phase Angle','S.E Long','S.E Lat','P.A Axis','Ls','Solar Elong'])
print (df)
df.plot(x ='Apparent Declination', y='Apparent R.A.', kind = 'scatter')
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy.io import ascii
c = SkyCoord(ra=10.625*u.degree, dec=41.2*u.degree, frame='icrs')
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
You say that your problem is only converting your input data -- of unspecified format -- to decimal degrees.  However, your posted code makes no attempt to implement this well-documented bit of arithmetic, and you've included several packages and other overhead having nothing to do with the conversion.

Comment: Hello, the code I've posted so far is what I have. I have not attempted the conversion yet because I am not sure where to start first.

Comment: Again, refer to those posting guidelines; explaining your status does not make the question appropriate.